# process xml file along with others in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to load 3 files to hive, 1 from db2,second from mysql and 3rd is XML and then process it in hive.
i have sqooped db2 and mysql file. but how to load xml file in hive along with others with same format.
i solution is first process it with PIG and convert it into CSV  format then process.

CAN I directly load XML file in hive in CSV format to process all the data together ? 
appreciate your reply

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XPathUDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF), check out [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlnol/archive/2012/12/13/hive-and-xml-file-processing.aspx) for more information